# DoctrineMigrationsBundle generates same migration every time

Tags: mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine-migrations

I have an entity with field `$usedMB`. I'm using Doctrine2 as ORM and DoctrineMigrationsBundle for DB migrations.

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class DeviceStatus
{
    ...

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="float", nullable=true, options={"unsigned":true})
     */
    private $usedMB;

    ...
}
```

If I execute command `php bin/console doctrine:migrations:diff`, I get the following line in the migrations file:
`ALTER TABLE device_status CHANGE used_mb used_mb DOUBLE PRECISION DEFAULT NULL`

After that, I execute command `php bin/console doctrine:migrations:migrate`, and I get the message that migration executed successfully.

But the problem is - if I execute `php bin/console doctrine:migrations:diff` again, I get the same line in the migrations file:
`ALTER TABLE device_status CHANGE used_mb used_mb DOUBLE PRECISION DEFAULT NULL`

Just to point out - no code changes were made between executing commands.

After that, I execute command php bin/console doctrine:migrations:migrate, and again - I get the message that migration executed successfully.
And that could go on forever.

This is how concrete field in DB looks:
[image: db field]

Can some please explain me why is the same migration generated every time?

Comment: Does `doctrine:schema:update --dump` returns the same query?

Comment: Yes, it is. It gives the exact same result.

Comment: Try to `clear:cache --env=dev`

Comment: After cache cleanup I get the same result :/

Comment: The problem is the "unsigned" option. If you look at the generated SQL it is missing. According to the Docs the annotation usage looks fine. I can reproduce this behaviour. Even trying to manually set the unsigned property in the DB after adding the Column doesn't help. Could possibly be a doctrine bug itself. Removing the unsigned option and it's working fine.

Comment: Yeah definitely doctrine bug, even found the open bug report: https://github.com/doctrine/dbal/issues/2380 to be fixed in doctrine 2.6 which is not yet released

Comment: Yeah. If I remove unsigned option, everything works. Thank you. Could you please c/p your comments, and create an answer, so I can accept it.
Maybe it would be helpful to some other people :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is a bug handling the "unsigned" option with doctrine itself.

Currently theres an open bug report for this topic in the respository:
https://github.com/doctrine/dbal/issues/2380

The fix should be released with v2.6